# Can't update array value in mysql

Tags: mysql, arrays, post, foreach, sql-update

I'm not sure what is the problem with my query, because I can't update my database with the latest value, but I can (print_r) the value.

```
$serial[$i]= $_POST['serial'][$i];
print_r($serial);
$a = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
print_r( $a);

$i=0;
 $i=0;
foreach($serial as $s => $m){
      $sqlw = "update speciform set nam5 = '$m[$i]' where nn = '$a[$i]' AND 
      nam11= CURDATE()";
      mysql_query($sqlw) or die(mysql_error());
$i++;
    }
```

Below is my table for update in (HTML and PHP):

[Update Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCRCs.png)

when I echo the $serial, I get this:-

[echo $serial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuE6x.png)

when I echo the $a, I get this:-[echo $a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7b8P3.png)

and my database is like this:-[Database Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeE8T.png)

Really need someone to help me because I'm currently blank with this problem.

Comment: Please learn about Prepared statements. You current query is very much open to SQL injection vulnerability

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya tq for your comments. I'll learn about that as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`foreach($serial as $s => $m) { ... }` will loop through the array `$serial` as you expect.

If you write :

```
foreach($serial as $s => $m)
{
    echo $m;
}
```

You'll notice that at each iteration, test1 test2 test3 and so on will be displayed.

Since `$m` is a string, `$m[0]` is the first **character**. Hence, `$m[$i]` will display the first character at first iteration, the second character at second iteration, and so on...

```
$sqlw = "UPDATE speciform SET nam5 = '" . $m . "' WHERE nn = '" . $a[$i] . "' AND nam11= CURDATE()";
```

This query is vulnerable to [SQL injections](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) but this is another topic. I **strongly** advice you to sanitize user inputs. Never trust a user.

Comment: Great!! Thank u, Thank u, Thank u!! I learn this from u. Thank you so much, it's works! Alright, I'll learn about  SQL too. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$sqlw = "update speciform set nam5 = '$m[$i]' where nn = '$a[$i]' AND 
      nam11= CURDATE()";
```

Change this query

```
$sqlw = "update speciform set nam5 = '$m' where nn = '$a[$i]' AND 
  nam11= CURDATE()";
```

Because as you have taken foreach loop so array of single element is their only in $m.